# Google sheet, images disappear randomly

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Using Google Sheets I'm trying to populate a list of countries with (among others) names, ISO-alfa2 code, and flags. I use this `IMAGE()` and  `ArrayFormula()` to get the flags from URL in my private server:

`=ARRAYFORMULA( IMAGE(URL/"&P7:P224&".png"))`
Where URL is the link hosting the flags, RANGE `P7:P222`  contains ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes (all in upper case). The flags in the URL labeled with the same ISO codes except with lower case.

As shown in the attached picture, some flags randomly don't show up despite that all ISO codes have been entered the same way (all upper case) and all the flags images are lower case.
[image]

**Things I tried:**

When using `LOWER(P7:P222)`, some flags don't show up.
When using `UPPER(P7:P222)` some different flags don't show up.
I used both Chrome and Firefox to view and edit the sheet.

Is there a way to fix this without changing the range to lower case or the images name to upper case? Is it something wrong with my formula or is it just the browser, HTTP/GET or Google app is misbehaving? Any input is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: Looks like this has nothing to do with case-sensitivity as I changed range `P7:P221` to LOWER case, however, the problem persists and some images randomly don't show up.. Does this mean the `IMAGE()` formula 
is broken?

IMPORTANT UPDATE: Further tested the following:

- Used`image()` to get images from Google Driver: no luck.
- Inserted images manually: they disappear after a while.
- Used ImageKit addon to insert images from URL (Google Driver and other servers): and via upload from my PC: Yield same results as using  `image()` formula.

I also changed the title of the question accordingly.

Link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nd1gbRm0eD2lvUa58jHjacdTYd7fqhGP4YpYeMZWRzo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Add demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view.

Comment: Rubén, updated with an editable version of the sheet.

Comment: IHMO demo spreadsheets should not be shared with edit access for anyone with the link b/c demo spreadsheet should not be changed.

Comment: The shared spreadsheet doesn't show the problem.

Comment: Sharing the sheet dramatically altered the problem, more flags showed up, still, some will not show up, there's no logical explanation as to why they don't as the sheet structure is the same.
Also, I disabled the edit feature I'm the shared sheet. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: "there's no logical explanation" that isn't completely true.

Comment: At least to me!

Comment: Did you try `=encodeurl()` ?  more info here : https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9199778?hl=en

Comment: pjmg, putting IMAGE() inside encodeurl() returns empty result all together.

Comment: I have to say the problem persists, images just appear and disappear randomly.
Come on SOF experts! I can really use your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the problem cause was client-specific.
In my case, it was that the adblocker (uBlock) somehow blocking most of the images indiscriminately.

The solution: Disabled uBlock adblocker on the relevant Google sheets page.

Answer (score 3):

It was the following Chrome Extension for me:
Google Docs Offline

Disabling that solved the issue for me.

Comment: That worked for me. But it's not a convenient fix because you lose local caching...